# Reversing stack elements MIPS logical error

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to MIPS and writing a program of stack which reverses the elements in array.. i have tried everything to see if anything is wrong.. If anyone who can guide me?

```
.data
array: .word 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 23, 33, 3, 1, 9
.word 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 3, 5, 7, 5
.word 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59
length: .word 30

.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:

la $t0, array
li $t1, 0 
lw $t2, length 
pushLoop:
lw $t4, ($t0) 
sw $t4, ($sp)
add $t2, $t1, 0 
add $t0, $t0, 4 
blt $t1, $t2, pushLoop 


la $t0, array 
li $t1, 0 
lw $t2, length 
popLoop:
lw $t4, ($sp)
addu $sp, $sp, 4 
sw $t4, ($t0) 
add $t1, $t1, 1 
add $t0, $t0, 4 
blt $t1, $t2, popLoop 



li $v0, 10 
syscall 
.end main
```

Comment: You can optimize the loop by calculating the end-pointer once ahead of the loop, then just `bne $t0, $t1` at the bottom of the loop.  Then you don't need a separate counter increment, just the two pointer increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in this program:

1. while you push something on satack you have to subtract the $sp by 4 bytes and then copy the operand to that
   location (in that order)

   I don't know how can you forget that since you correctly added $sp while popping ... anyway

   So you need to add `subu $sp, $sp, 4`.  (Or `addiu $sp, $sp, -4` if your assembler doesn't turn sub into add for you.)
2. in loop the `add $t2,$t1,0` is wrong .. you should do `$t1,$t1,1` (because you seem to increment by one like i = i + 1) .. this mistake indirectly
   causes your loop to work incorrectly which compares t1 and t2 registers (and you updated t2 register wrongly)

   Adding 0 is just a copy, so that's not what you want either.

Here is the corrected code.

```
.data
array: .word 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 23, 33, 3, 1, 9
.word 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 3, 5, 7, 5
.word 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59
length: .word 30

.text
.globl main


.ent main
main:

la $t0, array
li $t1, 0 
lw $t2, length 
pushLoop:
lw $t4, ($t0) 
subu $sp, $sp, 4 
sw $t4, ($sp)
add $t1, $t1, 1 
add $t0, $t0, 4 
blt $t1, $t2, pushLoop 


la $t0, array 
li $t1, 0 
lw $t2, length 
popLoop:
lw $t4, ($sp)
addu $sp, $sp, 4 
sw $t4, ($t0) 
add $t1, $t1, 1 
add $t0, $t0, 4 
blt $t1, $t2, popLoop 



li $v0, 10 
syscall 
.end main
```